# Como Colocar Item de lista en la primer columna de un Grid WPF

Tags: c#, lista, wpf, gridview

```
private void Hiperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog BuscarReportes = new OpenFileDialog();
            BuscarReportes.Multiselect = true;
            BuscarReportes.Filter = "Archivos|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
            BuscarReportes.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            if (BuscarReportes.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                foreach (string Archivo in BuscarReportes.FileNames)
                {
                    this.view.lbx_Archivos.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(Archivo));
                }
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ControlNotificacion.MostrarNotificacion("Se ha Producido un Error: " + ex, TipoNotificacion.Alerta, Posicion.InferiorDerecha);
        }
    }
```

En el evento anterior lleno una lista (lbx_Archivos).

Me gustaría si pueden apoyarme a como pasar esos elementos en la primer columna de un Grid.
Considerando que esa columna se llamará reportes y tendré dos columnas adicionales de nombre estatus y observaciones.

Comment: que componente de grilla estas usando? y como la definiste? y si esto es wpf, porque simplemente no haces un binding?

Comment: @gbianchi es un Grid común, tienes un ejemplo como aplicar lo del Binding lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asignar datos a un `GridView` del `WPF` debes definir su `ItemSource`  aunque en realidad asignando el `Items.Add()` tambien puede funcionar

[WPF - Gridview](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_gridview.htm)

pero deberias crear una clase, como ser

```
public class Archivo
{
   public string reportes {get;set;}
   public string estatus {get;set;}
   public string observaciones {get;set;}
}
```

Entonces defines el grid en el xaml

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Height = "299" Margin = "10,10,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment = "Top" Width = "497" Name = "ArchivoList">

     <ListView.View>
        <GridView> 
           <GridViewColumn Header = "reportes" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding reportes}" 
              Width = "100"/> 

           <GridViewColumn Header = "estatus" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding estatus}" 
              Width = "100"/>

           <GridViewColumn Header = "observaciones" DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding observaciones}" 
              Width = "100"/>

        </GridView> 
     </ListView.View>

  </ListView>
```

Es importante que el `DisplayMemberBinding = "{Binding ... }"` coincida con las propiedades de la clase, y luego desde codigo asignas los datos

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window { 

  public MainWindow() { 
     InitializeComponent(); 

  } 

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         foreach(var item in this.view.lbx_Archivos.Items)
         {
            ArchivoList.Items.Add(new Archivo() {reportes = item, estatus = "Activo", observaciones = "" }); 
         }
    }
}
```